# How to create dynamically a Hook in React?

Tags: reactjs

I know what I'm about to say may not be possible but I want to do something with functional components that I did in React with Class Components,

With Class Components, you can do this :

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
}
```

The this.state."e.target.name" is created dynamically with the value of e.target.name,

**but how in functional components (hooks), you set dynamically a hook according the value of the name of an input ?**

It would be something like this (don't shout, I know that can't be done :D) :

```
function handleChange(e) {
  set`${e.target.name.toUpperCase()`(e.target.value);
}
```

I know there's 99% that you tell me "that's not possible" but I really wanted to be sure,

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This has nothing to do with `hooks` itself, it's more on how you're defining your `state`. You can reproduce the behavior you want using `useState` like this

```
const Component = () =>{
    const [state, setState] = useState({})

    const onChange = e =>{
        const { target: {value, name } } = e

        setState(prev =>({
            ...prev,
            [name] : value
        }))
    }

}
```

Now if `state[name]` is `undefined` a new property is added, if `state[name]` is already defined the old `value` is overwrited

Comment: it's the first time that I see the "prev =>" right after the "setState", is this something required to do this? because I never used this

Comment: If you want to preserve the old properties. Now `state` is an object and `onChange` changes only one property of `state`, the other ones must remain the same

Comment: @Versifiction That's how you should update the state as the state updates are batched.

Comment: This solution is outstanding!

Comment: That is really helpfull, thank you